# stderr doesn't get captured when stdout=sys.stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I'm trying to run through `subprocess.run()` a command that will request user input via `stdout`, and in case the result is a failure, say why via `stderr`.

I want to capture `stderr` to show a friendlier error, but let `stdout` pass-through to the user's terminal. However, I only seem to be able to capture `stderr` if I'm also capturing `stdout` (either by explicitly passing `stdout=sys.stdout` or omitting it).

I'm no Python expert, and this whole subprocess/pipe/capture thing is getting messy for me. I'm trying to avoid going down `Popen` or looping output lines, if possible, as this seems to be an otherwise simple task. Could someone clarify what I'm doing wrong?

> In the examples below, after the user inputs `n`, the script would error out.
> I use `#>` to represent CLI output.

```py
result = subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=sys.stdout)
print(result)
#> Question? [y/n] (user input starts) n <enter>
#> error: blah blah
#> CompletedProcess(args=[...], returncode=1, stderr='')


### the same happens if stdout is omitted,
### or if I try to check captured stderr from CalledProcessError instead
try:
    subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, check=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print(vars(error))
#> (user input starts) n <enter>
#> {'returncode': 1, 'cmd': [...], 'output': None, 'stderr': ''}


### However, if I also capture stdout, it works as expected...
### But then, the user cannot really interact, since the question
### is captured and never shown. The same happens if I try..except.
result = subprocess.run(cmd, text=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result)
#> (user input starts) n <enter>
#> CompletedProcess(args=[...], returncode=1, stdout="Question? [y/n] ", stderr="\x07error: blah blah\n")
```

[A reproducible gist can be found here](https://gist.github.com/igorsantos07/160dc637eece5957125bb61e4746b424)... However, after some nudges from @Barmar, I created an example using a MariaDB image and the issue doesn't show up there as well - instead of everything going to `stderr` on the last code block, everything is going to `stdout` (which is bad but sort of expected).

I guess this could be closed as non-reproducible, unless someone get a great idea about my problem (which, again, isn't reproducible on the gist I wrote).

Comment: I can’t reproduce this (Python 3.8.10, some ancient Raspbian Linux version). Can you provide a [MCVE]? Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: There is a comment in the documentation which may explain the problem (but I cannot really parse well the documentation): https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.stdout -- so it may depends on the caller: both may be the same entity (not just pointing the same output)

Comment: `stdout=sys.stdout` doesn't capture stdout, it just passes it through to the original stdout. Which is the default if you don't use the `stdout` or `capture` options.

Comment: Are you sure the command is writing errors to `stderr`? All these symptoms are consistent with the error message going to `stdout`. What command are you running?

Comment: @Barmar the idea isn't to capture stdout, but to pass it through. I only want to capture stderr. And yep, I'm sure it's using stderr as well: check the last example when both are captured, each message goes to the right bucket.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when `cmd` runs this shell script: `echo "Question? [y/n]";read response;echo "error: blah blah" >&2`

Comment: Result is `CompletedProcess(args=['./teststderr.sh'], returncode=0, stderr='error: blah blah\n')`

Comment: Is it possible the command alters its behavior depending on whether stdout is a terminal or pipe? It looks like it writes errors to stdout when it's a terminal, but splits between stdout and stderr when stdout is a pipe.

Comment: I'm wrapping up a reproducible example, which is getting even odder :| It looks like the problem might be related to the output of input requests, actually?

Comment: [Reproducible script here](https://gist.github.com/igorsantos07/160dc637eece5957125bb61e4746b424). Will add to main question body as well.

Comment: See [here](https://discuss.python.org/t/builtin-function-input-writes-its-prompt-to-sys-stderr-and-not-to-sys-stdout/12955). `input()` writes the prompt to stderr rather than stdout in some cases. Unfortunately, this isn't mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: What the actual................... I even checked the docs for `input()` when writing the example, looking for that. But well, taking that out of the equation, I guess I can't create a reproducible example without a droppable database lol (the actual command is `mariadb-admin drop db123`, running from a docker container).

Comment: I have updated the example to use a MariaDB container........ and can't reproduce the problem either, using the same version we're running. The only difference is that, for some reason, the devops team decided they wanted to install MariaDB on an Ubuntu image, instead of using the MariaDB image directly. In this scenario, both prompt and error output go to `stdout`, so I give up :(